# Why does =SUM(A1:A10*2) resolve correctly?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say the sum of ranges A1:A10 is 100, why would =SUM(A1:A10*2) resolve to 200 instead of throwing an error?

I looked at the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) and it says:

> The SUM function adds values. You can add individual values, cell references or ranges or a mix of all three.

There is no mention of being able to handle multiplication (or anything other than addition). Am I missing something?

Comment: `A1:A10*2` will evaluate to an array of individual values.

Comment: So is it effectively doing A1*2, A2*2, ..., A10*2 and then A1+A2+...+A10?

Comment: Yes, use the 'Evaluate Formula' option to see the order in which Excel performs its calculations.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! 

I suppose this would mean that =SUM(A1:A10)*2 is faster but it's probably irrelevant given the range.

Comment: It would probably be faster indead, however it's about the idea here that you can include nearly any calculated array of values inside `SUM()`. Something `SUMPRODUCT()` did for older versions of Excel.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, you are really perfect for each of the explanations you provide, totally neat & clear., thank you again!